# Re-Dimensionar iframe a su contenido en vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Yo estoy desarrollando un sitio en el que tengo que incorporar un `iframe` que muestra el contenido de otro sitio, el problema que tengo es en el `height` del `iframe`, ya que este no se acomoda a su contenido.

Investigando encontré esta solución en `js` pero el problema es que no me sale en `vue JS`.

[Fuente de solución en JS.](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/height/)

**JS**:

```
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
    // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

**iframe**:

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="https://www.google.com.co" onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)"></iframe>
```

En `Vue JS` intente crear los métodos de la siguiente forma:

```
methods: {
    getDocHeight: function (doc) {
        doc = doc || document;
        // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
        var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
        var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
        return height;
    },
    setIframeHeight: function (id) {
        var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
        var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
        ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
        // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
        ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
        ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } 

}
```

También intente utilizar las funciones directamente de `Js` pero no me resulto.